# client side form validation not working for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. i have two models department and address and they are associated
   with one another but when i  use client side form validation address
   model fields are not getting validated. The javascript for
   validating associated model is not being generated.
2. **Department model**

   ```
   class Department < ActiveRecord::Base   
       attr_accessible :agency_head, :agency_head_rank, :department_type_id, :fax, :name,
                       :phone, :address_attributes
       validates :name , :length => { :minimum => 2 } , :presence => true
       validates :department_type_id , :agency_head,:agency_head_rank,:phone,:fax, :presence => true

       belongs_to :department_type
       belongs_to :address, :class_name => "Address", :foreign_key => "address_id"   
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :address,:allow_destroy => true
   end
   ```
3. **Address model**

   ```
   class Address < ActiveRecord::Base   
       attr_accessible :state, :street1, :street2, :town, :zipcode, :county   
       validate :street1 ,:street2,:town,:state,:county,:zipcode ,:presence => true   
       has_one :department  
   end
   ```
4. **view-page**

   ```
           <h1 id="form-title">Add New Department</h1>

           <%=form_for @department ,:validate=>true do |f|%>   
   <div    id="respond">
               <% if @department.errors.any? %>
               <div id="error_explanation">
                   <h2><%= pluralize(@department.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

                   <ul>
                       <% @department.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                       <li>
                           <%= msg %>
                       </li>
                       <% end %>
                   </ul>
               </div>
               <% end %>

               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="Department Name">Department&nbsp;Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
                   <%= f.text_field :name, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>
               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="Department Type">Department&nbsp;Type</label>
                   <%= f.collection_select :department_type_id, @dept_types, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
               </p>

               <%= f.fields_for :address, @department.address ,:validate=> true do |addr| %>
               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="Street1">Street 1</label>
                   <%= addr.text_field :street1 , :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>
               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="Street 2">Street 2</label>
                   <%= addr.text_field :street2, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>
               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="Town">Town</label>
                   <%= addr.text_field :town, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>

               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="State">State</label>
                   <%= addr.text_field :state, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>
               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="State">County</label>
                   <%= addr.text_field :county, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>

               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="Zip Code">Zip Code</label>
                   <%= addr.text_field :zipcode, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>

               <% end %>

               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="agency head">Agency Head</label><span class="required">*</span>
                   <%= f.text_field :agency_head, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>
               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="agency head rank">Agency Head Rank</label><span class="required">*</span>
                   <%= f.text_field :agency_head_rank, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>

               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="phone">Phone</label><span class="required">*</span>
                   <%= f.text_field :phone, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>
               <p class="comment-form-author">
                   <label for="fax">Fax</label><span class="required">*</span>
                   <%= f.text_field :fax, :size => 30, 'aria-required' => 'true'  %>
               </p>
                           </div>
                       <div class="spacer">
               <br/>
               <center>
                   <%= f.button " Submit ", :id => 'my_login_form_button' %>
               </center>           </div>          <% end %>       </div> </div>   </div> </div> </div>
   ```

Comment: between this is not a client side validation...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I find out my mistake use this one in address model.**

validates :street1 ,:street2,:town,:state,:county,:zipcode ,:presence => true

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery validate to validate your forms. It is much easier than doing it manually.